# WebStorm - NodeJS debug different folder

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm, remote-debugging

I have source of NodeJS application in `src` folder. But in folder `dist` I have copied app from source folder (it is copy 1:1) via webpack (but I think, it doesn't matter in this situation).

I have a question. Is it possible to make break point in `src` folder, run application from `dist` folder and run debug properly?

I've tried as Remote Debugging, but it doesn't work. I've set on port 5858 and  in WebStorm I can see "connected to localcohst:5858" too. (Also in browser I can enter on page `localhost:5858` and I can see some content).

In this case make break point in `dist` folder doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable [source maps generation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool) in Webpack by adding `devtool: "source-map"` to webpack.config.js.
Source maps describe the relation between compiled code in the dist folder that is actually executed and the source code where you have the breakpoints.

Comment: Source map is not generated for files copied by Webpack Copy Plugin.

Comment: there is no way then. For client-side debugging, remote url mappings would help in such cases. But there is no way to specify such mappings for node.js debugging, so sourcemaps is the only way to go